# Effect of doubling first payment on a mortgage

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Suppose I want to buy a \$200000 home, and take a 30 year mortgage on it. My interest rate is 7%. I have saved \$20000 to make a down payment.

**Question:** What will my monthly payment be? What will be the total amount that I pay the bank? Finally, if I double my first payment, then how long will it take before the loan is paid off?

**Work:** For the first question I have \$1197.55 thanks to the down payment which means I pay the bank \$431,118.00, but I cannot figure out the last question. I know the answer is allegedly 29 years and 3 months, but I cannot figure out at all how this is obtained.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

$$180000 = K a_{\overline{360} \rceil j} = K \frac{1 - (1 + 0.07/12)^{-360}}{(0.07/12)} = 150.308K,$$ hence $K = 1197.5444913$ is the level payment; rounding up ensures the payment is in full, since choosing $K = 1197.54$ means that the final payment is about $0.675$ short.

If the first payment is doubled, then the present value of the cash flow at $m$ months is $$K a_{\overline{m} \rceil j} + Kv,$$ thus we seek the smallest $m$ such that this expression equals $180000$; i.e., $$m \ge -\frac{\log \left(\frac{1448449}{1440000}-\frac{1050}{K}\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{1207}{1200}\right)} \approx 352.0013.$$  Thus the loan is paid off upon the $352^{\rm th}$ payment.  If we choose $K = 1197.54$ (the rounded down value) then the final payment will be short about $0.883$; if we choose the precise value of $K$, then the final payment will be short by about $0.208$.  If we choose the rounded up value of $K$ the final payment will result in overpayment by $0.62$.

Another way to reason about the second part--i.e., doubling the initial payment--is to note that doing so effectively increases the down payment made by the *present value* of the excess of the first installment.  That is to say, if you are supposed to pay $1197.55$ each month, then the present value of that first month's excess payment at the time the loan is taken out, is $1197.55(1 + 0.07/12)^{-1} = 1190.60$.  Thus you are in effect looking at a loan of $200000 - 20000 - 1190.60 = 178809.40$ with level payments of $1197.55$ per month at a nominal rate of $7\%$ convertible monthly, and you need to find the term of such a loan.

Comment: Hm interesting. I came up with $352.086386188$. Guess there are some rounding issues. Regardless, it looks like the answer should be 29 years and 4 months as opposed to 29 years and 3 months no?

Comment: @rudy Yes.  Another way to put it is that by doubling the initial payment, the loan is paid off 8 months early, not 9.

Comment: Quick aside on what I did (maybe you can point out where some imprecision was introduced on my part perhaps): I basically let the amount of the annuity be $A_f=R+R(1+i)+R(1+i)^2+\cdots+2R(1+i)^{n-1}$ where $R$ is the periodic payment, and then I went from there. Anything wrong with that (the last term of the sum being $2R(1+i)^{n-1}$ because it represents twice the monthly payment $R$ being paid out at the beginning). If this isn't correct, then I am curious as to how our end results are so close. With such large numbers I would expect the error to be larger.